# Given $d(x) = \sqrt x + 3$ and $g(x) = 3\sqrt x - 2$, find $k(x) = 4\left(\frac{g}{d}\right)(x)$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

> Given: $d(x) = \sqrt x + 3$ and $g(x) = 3\sqrt x - 2$, find $k(x) = 4\left(\frac{g}{d}\right)(x)$.

The answer I got was:

$$\frac{12x-44\sqrt{x}+24}{x-9}$$

Any input would be much appreciated thanks.

Comment: Thanks Ayman Hourieh for taking the time to edit my problem.

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks to Zev Chonoles too (also made improvements).

Answer (score 2):

You're correct.$$4\left(\frac{g}{d}\right)(x)=4\cdot\frac{g(x)}{d(x)}=4\cdot\frac{3\sqrt{x}-2}{\sqrt{x}+3}=\frac{12\sqrt{x}-8}{\sqrt{x}+3}\cdot\frac{(\sqrt{x}-3)}{(\sqrt{x}-3)}=\frac{12x-44\sqrt{x}+24}{x-9}$$

Comment: Thanks Zev! not sure what I would do without your input.

Comment: The questioner's answer is not correct since he has a 14 instead of 24.

Comment: @Barry Actually, it was $24$ in the [original revision](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/425738/1). Fixed now.